# How to access a property of a model in rails 4 from a js.erb file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using jQuery's autocomplete method for a search field. However, I don't know how to populate data from the Model in a javascript js.erb file.

I'm using the following code:

```
availableTags = <%= Course.all.title %>
jQuery ->
  $('#search').autocomplete
    source: availableTags
```

I want to access the title property from `Course` model but it doesn't work. It gives a no property found error.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT SOLUTION by Max:I give you the code with standard JavaScript syntax because is no longer coffescript when you rename the file with js.erb extension:

```
    $(function() {
    var availableTags = <%= Course.pluck(:title) %>;
    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
```

Comment: It does'nt work since `Course.all` gives you a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object which is like a lazy-loading array of Course objects.

Comment: Ok Max, thanks for your explanation and also thanks to craig for edit my post with a great improved grammar. Sorry for my english i will work hard to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pluck to select a single column from the database:

```
availableTags = <%= Course.pluck(:title).to_json %>
jQuery ->
  $('#search').autocomplete
    source: availableTags
```